# How to execute multiple tags using KarateOptions?

Tags: karate

I need to execute multiple tags from my runner class

Currently its like below

```
@KarateOptions(tags = {"SMOKE"})
public class TestRunner
```

I am using parallel execution.
I need to execute something like (tags = {"SMOKE","REGRESSION"})

I tried passing like above with two tags and no tests are getting executed. I am using karate version 0.9.5

Also I tried calling like below.

```
Results results = Runner.path("classpath:some/package").tags("SMOKE","REGRESSION").parallel(5);
```

Both cases aren't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an AND query. Do this:

`SMOKE,REGRESSION`